# Are theories about the universe or ontological realities that cannot be yet proven considered to be metaphysics theory?

Tags: metaphysics, ontology

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Metaphysical_theories

Are theories about the universe or ontological realities that cannot be yet proven considered to be metaphysics theory?

I was wondering why there are so few theories on the above page. For instance, there's a theory that says that space is infinitely divisible, another theory that says that space is not infinite, there's a theory that says that the shape of the universe is curved so that you will never reach a wall separating the universe from "what's outside" and so on, and yet these theories don't appear, it's as though they're classified under a different category.

I would be interested in researching about these theories and reading about them.

Comment: Indeed according to your definition "theories about the universe or ontological realities that cannot be yet proven considered to be metaphysics theory", then ZFC set theory is also a metaphysical theory since its consistency cannot be proven by itself alone and the choice of what type of large cardinal axioms to be added has yet to be decided by mathematicians community to pin it down, thus the whole mathematics are metaphysical theories since ZFC set theory is currently its most population foundation. Similar situations hold for other foundations such as type theory, category theory, etc...

Comment: Even what has been proven to exist can be properly called metaphysics, at least in the sense that there are few aspects of it without additional interpretation.